# What is the minimum buffer zone to get a certain amount of points within the zone?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I have one map with lines and another map with points. I want to find the distance of the buffer zone to be such so the amount of points that are in the buffer zone to reach a certain number. For example what is the buffer zone to get, 50% of all the points in the buffer zone?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some images showing a typical example of the configuration of your data?

Comment: So you see the lines and I want to find the buffer to be such so as a certain amount of points to be in the zone.

Answer (score 4):

How about this for an idea. Run your data through the near tool to create a table of distances. Sort this table by distance then identify the distance that is your 50% of points. This would be the buffer distance.

Comment: Due to ambiguity on "within" at exactly the buffer distance,  you may want to use a value halfway between the 50% mark and the next value. You may find that more than exactly half of the features qualify.

Comment: The near tool does not seem to make the work for this, as there are more than one lines and i want to know the buffer zone that should be applied to all the lines so as the total number of points reaches a certain number. Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: @dimitris: For that, you could first join all the lines and then run the "near" tool with that.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Also, export to excel does the work after the near tool to further process with histograms or such analysis.

Comment: @dimitris Actually, rather than using the Near tool you might want to consider the [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) tool. It can do multiple near features, so you don't have to join the lines and it does not modify the original data.